Graded cyclic properties in tensor calculus formalism of supergravity
I am trying to understand the chapter 4 of https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0204035. I want to obtain equation 4.19 in this article.
First let me summarized some equations we need
Denoting the gauge transformation as
\begin{align}
\delta_{\hat{\xi}} = \hat{\xi}^M \Delta_M T
\end{align}
where $\Delta_M$ is graded derivations,
\begin{align}
\Delta_M(T_1 T_2) = (\Delta_M T_1) T_2 + (-1)^{|M||T_1|} T_1(\Delta_M T_2)\tag{4.6}
\end{align}
Denoting
\begin{align}
[\Delta_M, \Delta_N] = - F_{MN}{}^{P} \Delta_P\tag{4.16}
\end{align}
with $$[X,Y]= XY - (-1)^{|X||Y|} YX\tag{4.13}$$ graded commutator, the graded cyclic sum as
$$\sum_{MNP} X_{MNP} = (-1)^{|M||P|} X_{MNP} + (-1)^{|N||M|} X_{NPM} + (-1)^{|P||N|} X_{PMN}\tag{4.18}$$
The paper states
\begin{align}
\sum_{MNP} [\Delta_M, [\Delta_N,\Delta_P]] =0\tag{4.17} 
\end{align}
implies
\begin{align}
\sum_{MNP} (\Delta_M F_{NP}{}^{Q} + F_{MN}{}^{R} F_{RP}{}^{Q}) =0\tag{4.19}
\end{align}
I want to obtain this from the commutator.

The followings are my trial
\begin{align}
[\Delta_M, [\Delta_N, \Delta_P]] 
= [\Delta_M, - F_{NP}{}^{Q} \Delta_Q]
\end{align}
From this I know the second term of i.e,. $F^2$ comes but I have no idea where the $\Delta_M F_{NP}{}^{Q}$ terms come.

Briefly speaking, eq. (4.19) follows by applying the graded commutator algebra (4.16) to the graded Jacobi identity (4.17), use the graded Leibniz rule (4.6), and finally assume that the graded derivations $\Delta_Q$ are linearly independent.

The term with $\Delta$ on the field strength arises from the identity
$[\Delta_A , X^B \Delta_B] = \Delta_A X^B \Delta_B + (-1)^{|B|} X^B \Delta_A \Delta_B - X^B \Delta_B \Delta_A = \Delta_A X^B \Delta_B - X^B [\Delta_B , \Delta_A]~,$
where the graded Leibniz rule has been used.
